# GWT Acegi alternative

Tags: gwt, inversion-of-control, spring, guice, spring-security

I'm starting new project. The client interface is based on GWT (and GXT) I have no say it's predetermined. However I can pick and choose as far as server side so I can have some fun and hopefully learn something new in the process. Some requirements are :

- Exchange with server will be through use of JSON, most if not all of UI will be generated by GWT (JS) on the client, so the client/serve exchange will be limited to data exchange as much as possible
- No Hibernate (it's not really supported on the proprietary db I will be connecting to). In the past projects people would use JDBC or iBATIS
- Some sort of IoC (I'm thinking Guice just to stick with Google)
- Some sort of Security framework based on LDAP. In the past we would use Spring security (Acegi) but it wasn't ideal and we had to customize it a lot

So basically should I stick with tried-and-true Spring/Acegi or try something based on Guice? And what that "something" would be and how mature is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nether of the above answers gave me any practical ideas (or almost any) here's formula I ended up with:

Maven + [GXT](http://www.extjs.com/products/gwt/) + [GWT and Guice](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2009/09/14/guice-with-gwt/) + [iBaGuice](http://ibaguice.googlecode.com/svn/site/1.0-beta-1/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Apache Shiro](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/). It seems to be gaining ground, with no reference to Spring.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to do IOC on client and server, go with [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/). You can use Guice on the server, and its brother [GIN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) on the client.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around - GIN (GWT INjection) on client and Guice on server?

Comment: Igor's right "GIN (GWT INjection) brings automatic dependency injection to Google Web Toolkit client-side code"